# Block youtube.com via `iptables`

Tags: firewall, iptables

For productivity reasons, I want to block access to YouTube.

---

What I have tried. I started by running:

```
dig A youtube.com +short
```

and then feeding the resulting address(es) to

```
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -o $SomeInterface -p all --dst $address -j DROP
```

---

This does not work. Specifically:

- youbute.com is reachable, works fine.
- This very same method works for other sites.

What am I missing? And what should I do differently?

Comment: What you should do is to get help that isn't technical in nature. Whatever you can technically do you can technically undo.

Comment: You are missing that Youtube isn't hosted by a single IP address. IPTables is simply ill-suited for this task.

Answer (score 0):

I handle this kind of task by running my own DNS server.  I primarily use it for adblocking, but it also works to prevent contact with other sites as well.

In the DNS server configuration, I have a DNS zone configured called "adblocking.zone" and for any query sent to that zone, it returns the loopback address (127.0.0.1) -- but you could make it anything you wanted it to be.

Then, in the named.conf file I have sites I want to block pointed to the adblocking zone.  The entries can be specific host names, or entire domains.  For example, I don't want my windows machines automatically updating, and since microsoft no longer gives us that option, I just "redirect" all of the windows update domains; like this:

```
zone  "windowsupdate.com" { type master; file "adblocking.zone"; };
zone  "mp.microsoft.com" { type master; file "adblocking.zone"; };
zone  "msedge.net" { type master; file "adblocking.zone"; };
```

That's just a few examples, there are many others.

If a time comes up where I want to allow access, ie. when I'm good and ready to apply a windows update, I simply comment-out those entries, restart the dns service and then access them as normal.  Easy peasy.

If you aren't quite tech savvy enough to operate your own internal DNS server from scratch, you can also use PiHole to do the same thing.  Within pihole, you'd just "blacklist" the domain.  It's pretty friendly and easy to use, so maybe give it a try.

The ultimate result of either of these approaches is that the domain (ie. youtube.com) is unresolvable to a real address and your browser won't be able to connect to it.